# Translating "Content: Link" in a Drupal 7 View

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I am working on my first Drupal 7 site that has internationalization. My site is in both English and Spanish. Generally I am pretty happy with the way it's going so far. The basis of my translation is using the *Entity Translation Module* and it works great, Views are translated seamlessly.

However, I have run into a snag, When I create a View and add "`Content: Link`" as a field, essentially a "read more..." link to the node, I am finding no way to translate the "Read more..." text that I enter into the "`Text to display`" textbox. My guess is because it's not actual content in the node that's been translated. I've looked around here, on drupal.org and my google-foo is failing me too. Just looking for some suggestions on how to do this.

[image]

Comment: I won't put this as an answer as it may not be exactly what you want, the [Translation Table module](http://drupal.org/project/translation_table) will let you set translations for arbitrary strings in the system. Since Views is almost definitely going to pass the 'Read more...' string through the `t()` function that module will make your translation work for as many languages as you like across the site

Comment: Thanks for the link. That module did not do what I need but in fact it led me to i18n Views (http://drupal.org/node/641082#comment-4951734) which is what I needed and it solved the problem. I also think I'll have a need for Translation Table too. If you want to officially answer, I will +1 it.

Comment: :No probs I've added it as an answer, you never know it might help someone out someday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I <del>won't</del> didn't put this as an answer as it may not be exactly what you want, the Translation Table module will let you set translations for arbitrary strings in the system.

Since Views is almost definitely going to pass the 'Read more...' string through the t() function that module will make your translation work for as many languages as you like across the site